# How to get featured image of a product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Please tell me where I am going wrong . Product featured image is not showing up.

```
   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 80, 'product_cat' => 'profiler', 'orderby' => 'rand' );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

    <div class="dvThumb col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 profiler-select profiler<?php echo the_title(); ?>" data-profile="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">

    <img src="<?php  get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">

    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

    <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    
    </div>
```

I have already added a featured image in back end

Comment: `$product->get_image( $size, $attr)`

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I got the solution .
I tried this .

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
                                        
    <img src="<?php  echo $image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
```

Comment: I know this is the accepted answer but,

what is the point of the $img_url? This would work with just echoing $image[0]

Comment: This solution does not account for the ALT tag or responsiveness.  Accessible compliance is huge in the USA and becoming more prominent worldwide.  Solutions which only get the image URL and promote an empty ALT tag puts you and your clients at massive risk of accessibility discrimination and potential lawsuits.  Please lean on WordPress ( `wp_get_attachment_image( $product->get_image_id(), 'large' );` ) to render the HTML for you, which provides additional wins such as mobile responsiveness (providing multiple image sizes for various browser widths), ALT content and titles.

Comment: I certainly agree with you, @StephanRobberts.  The whole thing could be written as:

echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id ), [ 30, 30 ] );

Answer (score 54):

The answers here, are way too complex. Here's something I've recently used:

```
<?php global $product; ?>
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() ); ?>" />
```

Using `wp_get_attachment_url()` to display the

Comment: Better to use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` because it always returns an image, also if the attachment is a video, or a pdf. And you can specify size too.
Then:
`wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail' )[0]`

Answer (score 17):

I would just use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` instead of `get_the_post_thumbnail()`

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->post->ID); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Best way for WordPress >= 4.4.

Answer (score 11):

`WC_Product::get_image()` – Returns the main product image.

**Usage**

```
$string = WC_Product::get_image( $size, $attr, $placeholder );
```

**Parameters**

`$size` - ( string ) optional default: woocommerce_thumbnail

`$attr` - ( array ) optional – Image attributes.

`$placeholder` - ( bool ) optional default: 1 – True to return `$placeholder` if no image is found, or false to return an empty string.

**Returns**

string

```
$product->get_image('thumbnail');
```

Answer (score 8):

In WC 3.0+ versions the image can get by below code.

```
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $item->get_product_id() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
echo $image_url[0]
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and solved it by using the default woocommerce hook to display the product image.

```php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail('woocommerce_full_size');
endwhile;
```

Available parameters:

- woocommerce_thumbnail
- woocommerce_full_size

Answer (score 5):

I did this and it works great

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

get_the_post_thumbnail function returns html not url of featured image. You should use get_post_thumbnail_id to get post id of featured image and then use wp_get_attachment_image_src to get url of featured image.

Try this:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 80, 'product_cat' => 'profiler', 'orderby' => 'rand' );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
    <div class="dvThumb col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-3 profiler-select profiler<?php echo the_title(); ?>" data-profile="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
        <?php $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->post->ID)); ?>
        <?php if($featured_image) { ?>
        <img src="<?php $featured_image[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop->post->ID; ?>">
        <?php } ?>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: hi limexs i already got the solution ,, but thanks for your answer...can you please tell me if i want to give a data variable to a particular product from back end  (woocommerce) than which field should i use (SKU or tag or there something else to add a identifier) . Since this unique identifier i want to use as html data variable... i hope you got my aquestion

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't understand the question. You're already using post_id and I think this is sufficient to identify the product.

Comment: limexs: actually i am upgrading a project to woocommerce .. so i need to store another identifier , which is already present in the existing project

Comment: alright, got it, you can use custom field for this.

Comment: <?php $featured_image[0]; ?> should be <?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
    $product_meta = get_post_meta($post_id);
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $product_meta['_thumbnail_id'][0], 'full' );
?>
```

You can change the parameters according to your needs.

Comment: there's an extra parentheses, wp_get_attachment_image( $product_meta['_thumbnail_id'][0], 'full' );