# WooCommerce product image filename in product title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I recently started a WooCommerce project for a photographer client. I installed the commercial WooCommerce Photography extension and the Product Add-Ons extension. The client wants to add the product image title (filename) to the name of the product. Is there a way to do it somehow?

The WooCommerce Photography extension creates individual products from the photos you upload. Every product has one photo as a product image.

Basically, what I want to achieve is to show the filename of the main product image inside the name of the generated product. As long as I have it in the order details page, I am good. Anyone with a similar experience?

Comment: Your question has probably not received enough attention because there's currently no evidence you've attempted to solve the problem yourself. Right now it looks like a scope for a paid job. I'd advise editing your question with the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Based on what I have understood from your question, following might be the solution for your problem.

**First get featured image url.** 
Ref: [How to get featured image of a product in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837968/how-to-get-featured-image-of-a-product-in-woocommerce/32838338)

**Now use this URL to get filename.** Ref: https://gist.github.com/wooki/2709106

Once you get filename, you can echo it wherever needed or you can use this all in single-product template or order-details template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions are helpful.